# Ramda reduce string to replace previous one

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have this list of strings that I’d like to reduce using ramda:

```
["red blue green", "pink blue green", "red orange green", "red blue black"]
```

I’d like to reduce the list so that I’m left with:

```
"pink orange black"
```

So essentially only replacing the difference from the previous string, without overwriting the whole string.

The steps should be:

```
"red blue green"
"pink blue green"
"pink orange green"
"pink orange black"
```

This is what I currently have:

```
const strings = ["red blue green", "pink blue green", "red orange green", "red blue black"]

const replaceString = (old, acc) => R.replace(old, acc, acc)

R.reduce(replaceString, R.head(strings))
```

Comment: wouldn't the end result be `"red blue black"` ?

Comment: Could you explain what you'd expect to see at each step? I can't make sense of how you get from your input to your suggested output.

Comment: Sure, have gone ahead and updated that above.

Comment: So at step `n`, you're replacing the value at index `n - 1`?  It doesn't matter what's in the other parts of the string?

Comment: That’s right. I think I actually need to go for a regex to replace only the difference from the previous string. I tried using `R.difference` but with not much luck.

Comment: You're talking about the difference from the "previous" string, but you seem to mean difference (in some form) from the original string.  Is that right?

Comment: Yeah that’s right. Let me know if there’s anything to re-word on the question — I don’t think I’ve done a very good job in making it clear.

Comment: What would be the expected result if someone passed a fifth string of "pink blue purple"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have code that gets the answer you want from the initial data.  But I really don't know if it solves your general problem:

```
const colors = ["red blue green", "pink blue green", "red orange green", "red blue black"];

const fn = pipe(
  map(split(' ')),    // [['red', 'blue', 'green'], ['pink', 'blue' 'green'], 
                      //   ['red', 'orange', 'green'], ['red' 'bluee', 'black']]
  flatten,            // ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 'blue' 'green', 
                      //   'red', 'orange', 'green', 'red' 'bluee', 'black']
  countBy(identity),  // {red: 3, blue: 3, green: 3, pink: 1, orange: 1, black: 1}
  filter(equals(1)),  // {pink: 1, orange: 1, black: 1}
  keys,               //  ['pink', 'orange', 'black'
  join(' ')           //  'pink orange black'
)

fn(colors); //=> 'pink orange black'
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20colors%20%3D%20%5B%22red%20blue%20green%22%2C%20%22pink%20blue%20green%22%2C%20%22red%20orange%20green%22%2C%20%22red%20blue%20black%22%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20fn%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20map%28split%28%27%20%27%29%29%2C%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%5B%5B%27red%27%2C%20%27blue%27%2C%20%27green%27%5D%2C%20%5B%27pink%27%2C%20%27blue%27%20%27green%27%5D%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20%20%5B%27red%27%2C%20%27orange%27%2C%20%27green%27%5D%2C%20%5B%27red%27%20%27bluee%27%2C%20%27black%27%5D%5D%0A%20%20flatten%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%5B%27red%27%2C%20%27blue%27%2C%20%27green%27%2C%20%27pink%27%2C%20%27blue%27%20%27green%27%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20%20%27red%27%2C%20%27orange%27%2C%20%27green%27%2C%20%27red%27%20%27bluee%27%2C%20%27black%27%5D%0A%20%20countBy%28identity%29%2C%20%20%2F%2F%20%7Bred%3A%203%2C%20blue%3A%203%2C%20green%3A%203%2C%20pink%3A%201%2C%20orange%3A%201%2C%20black%3A%201%7D%0A%20%20filter%28equals%281%29%29%2C%20%20%2F%2F%20%7Bpink%3A%201%2C%20orange%3A%201%2C%20black%3A%201%7D%0A%20%20keys%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20%5B%27pink%27%2C%20%27orange%27%2C%20%27black%27%0A%20%20join%28%27%20%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20%27pink%20orange%20black%27%0A%29%0A%20%20%0Afn%28colors%29)**.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Reduce was definitely the wrong to go with from the outset.